# SQL Server data to SQLite database

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a SQL Server table with some 20000+ rows of data and same I have to insert into the sqlite database creating at runtime. Kindly suggest which will be the best method to import the data?

I have two sets of code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

using (var con = new SqlConnection(classlayer.SQLconnectionstring))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(spname, con))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.Fill(table);
}

string qry = "Select * from " + tablename;
var sqliteAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(qry, sqlitecon);
var cmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(sqliteAdapter);
sqliteAdapter.Update(table);
```

or this one

```
string MyConString = "SERVER=SERVER;DATABASE=mydb;User ID=sa;Password=password;";
string query = "";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MyConString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Code,Name,route from Localities", connection);

SqlDataReader Reader;

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=W:\\Localities.db;Version=3;");

connection.Open();
conn.Open();

Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int i = 0;

while (Reader.Read())
{
    query = "Insert into Localities(Code,Name,route) values('" + Reader.GetValue(0).ToString() + "','" + Reader.GetValue(1).ToString() + "','" + Reader.GetValue(2).ToString()  + "')";
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn);
    i = i + cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```